# copy contents of dto to another similar dto

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, dto

I have 2 very similar dto object. I have shown a sample code below, but the actual 2 dto with which I am working have 39 and 40 properties in it. 
My question is that is there an easier way to copy contents of QuoteDto to Quote2Dto.

I am makinga call to a legacy project which gives me QuoteDto object. I than have to make call to a new rest service project which only accepts Quote2Dto object

Let me know if you need any more code.

```
    public abstract class QuoteDto
    {
        public virtual bool IsWaive { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsExpired { get; set; }
    }

public abstract class Quote2Dto
    {
        public virtual bool IsWaive { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsExpired { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsCancel { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) (or similar library) is used. It can copy same properties without any pre-configuration needed. But you can always configure more advanced property mappings.

[Here you can find Getting Started Guide.](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here.

Your first options is to use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to copy properties. There are some advanced configurations to AutoMapper if you would need more advanced configuration.

The second option is to create a method inside your DTO, that takes the other DTO and copies the properties.(Basically copying the properties manually.)

It would look something like this:

```
class FirstSampleDTO
{
    public int RandomProperty { get; set; }
    public int RandomProperty2 { get; set; }
    public int RandomProperty3 { get; set; }

    private void CopyDTOData(SecondSampleDTO dto)
    {
        dto.RandomProperty = this.RandomProperty;
        dto.RandomProperty2 = this.RandomProperty2;
        dto.RandomProperty3 = this.RandomProperty3;
    }
}

class SecondSampleDTO
{
    public int RandomProperty { get; set; }
    public int RandomProperty2 { get; set; }
    public int RandomProperty3 { get; set; }

    private void CopyDTOData(FirstSampleDTO dto)
    {
        dto.RandomProperty = this.RandomProperty;
        dto.RandomProperty2 = this.RandomProperty2;
        dto.RandomProperty3 = this.RandomProperty3;
    }

}
```

(This in in case you already have the data of the dto.)

I would suggest using the second method if you are not going to do that much of a mapping.